# What libraries can log javascript usage at runtime?

Tags: javascript

We have a web application, is there any library that we can add to the code base in order to log any method invocation at run-time?

**EDIT**
More details..

1) The application is running in production and we need to send the logs back to the server once in a while

2) I can't wrap any function invocation, that's why I am looking for a library that will do some sort of instrumentation or another work around..so in essence I am looking for an auto-logger

Comment: Do you want to log invocations on the client or server side? If client, do you want to send the log back to the server or just keep it available for the user?

Comment: I want to take the logs on the client side and send it back to some server once in a while..

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript runs on the client computer, so any logging that you could see would have to

- Be on a client computer that you control (e.g. for debugging purposes), OR
- Send the log file back to the server at some point for you to analyze.

If you are asking about the first, [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript/) can log function calls.

If you are after more general logging that *could* also send results back to the server, [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/) is worth looking at.  Have a look specifically at the [AjaxAppender](http://log4javascript.org/demos/ajax.html).

Comment: I need to send the results back and I can't use FireBug since it's a production system..I rather not change the client-side code, since it's not my code, I just want to add this library that will take the logs for me

Comment: Those are the only options I'm aware of

Comment: To the downvoter: Please leave a comment if you think something is inaccurate.

Comment: thanks, I wonder if I can access the Chrome Developer Tools/FireBug programmatically?

Comment: Not that I'm aware.  Note that an arbitrary end user will not necessarily be running Chrome or have FireBug installed.